# Can't see all Javadoc comments

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I'm hovering over some variables and methods in Eclipse.  I can see the packages and method signatures, but not the comments.  I did hover over one of my classes and I can see the comments there.  Is there a way to turn this on automatically for methods and variables?

Comment: What happens if you try to open up the class for the variable involved (Ctrl+click)?

Comment: Go to `Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Hovers` and test the different hover options (make sure the needed boxes are checked).

Comment: @chrylis, I tried that and I have the default settings on.

Comment: @Chrylis, It already had the default changes so I made no changes.  I still have the issue.

Comment: Please reply to *my* comment and not someone else's.

Comment: @Chrylis, not sure what you mean.  I don't see an option to reply to your comment specifically.  You have a comment to my question and I'm following up with a comment about your comment.

Comment: It really looks like you were responding to 1803511, not me. You didn't say what happened if you Ctrl+click on the class for the variable.

Comment: @chrylis, When I control-click on the click name of the class, it opens up the file for that class.  So I can see the comments that way, just not with hover.

Comment: Then there's probably a problem with the index. That indicates the source for the classes is available and attached.